# Why do long-format data structures take more memory in R?

Tags: r, data-structures

When working with large data sets, I notice that melting/gathering data takes up much more memory on my machine than when the data set is wide.

Example:

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
test <- mtcars %>%
     rownames_to_column() %>%
     gather()

object.size(mtcars)

#6736 bytes

object.size(test)

#16960 bytes
```

Both objects are storing the same data, but the first is wide and the second is long.  The long version is nearly triple the size.

Why is that?

Comment: compare the dimensions of the objects... 32x11 vs 384*2. Data that is this long has a lot of duplication in the key column

Comment: Also apples and oranges. `mtcars` is sensible, your `test` is not as you force all values to be of type `character`.

Comment: Makes sense.  Duplication and type conversion takes up more memory.  Thanks!